# Export specific fields on XML extraction in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson

I am using `@XmlRootElement` annotation to get XML data from the database.

Right now, if I put `@XmlTransient` to getters, the fields are ignored.

For example:

```
public class Student {
    private Integer studentId;
    private String studentName;

    @XmlTransient // Do not get student id
    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return this.studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return this.studentName;
    }

    ...// Setter goes here
```

Then, `student ids` are not appear in the XML file.

However, can I do this in the **opposite** way?  I want to specify fields that I want to have in the XML file - there are too many fields in the Student class.

My server(Spring Framework 3.2.3) also uses the `Jackson` library, so I wonder I could use it if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could annotate your class with:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
```

Now you have to explicitly map properties in order to be serialized. See the Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html

Comment: Thanks for helping me! but when I put '@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)' to the Student class, it doesn't load anything.  How can I specify fields?

Comment: Figured out: putting @XmlAttribute to the getter seems to work.